# Prove Uniform Convergence on $\frac{cos(n\pi x))}{n}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence

Trying to prove uniform convergence and having a bit of difficulty working out $$ f_n(x)=\frac{cos(n\pi x)}{n}$$ as  $n \to \infty$ on $x \in[0,1]$. I know that obviously because $n \to \infty$ then the denominator will be $\infty$ and the whole equation will tend $\to 0$.

However I am trying to prove whether or not this series of $f_n$ is uniformly convergent. So ultimately I am looking to figure out if there is an $x$ value which makes $$f_n(x) \not= 0 $$

I think due to the $\cos$, any $x$ going into it will only come out $\in [-1,1]$, then it would have to $= 0$. Just looking for some confirmation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f_n(x)$ has any right to be nonzero. Nevertheless $f_n$ tends to zero both pointwise and uniformly...

Comment: brilliant, so in this case, $f_n(x)$ would be uniformly continuous?

Comment: Are you asking about uniform continuity or uniform convergence? These are two different notions. The first is a property of a single function, the second is a property of a sequence of functions.

Comment: convergence sorry, excuse my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for all $x$, $|\cos(x)|\le 1$.  Therefore, we can write

$$\left|\frac{\cos(n\pi x)}{n}\right|\le \frac1n <\epsilon$$

whenever $n>\frac1\epsilon$.

Comment: very helpful, easier way of thinking of it

Comment: Pleased to hear that this was useful!

Answer (score 0):

"uniform convergence of a sequence of functions" and "uniform continuity of a function" are two different concepts.

One can ask

- (1) if a sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to some function *on* the interval $[0,1]$
- (2) or if each $f_n$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $[0,1]$.

(2) has nothing to do with the proof of (1). On the other hand, if you are asking (2) *per se*, then you might want to know a theorem in real analysis which says that any continuous real function on a closed interval is uniformly continuous.

For (1), all you need is that the cosine function is bounded.

Comment: convergence is what i was after, made an error, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're clear on the definition of uniform convergence. Specifically, you should be asking if there is a large $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all small $\epsilon > 0$ where $\epsilon$ does not depend on $N$, $n$, or $x$, for all $n>N$, you have the bound

$$\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right| < \epsilon$$

for some function $f(x)$. In your case, as you said $n$ is going to be dominating the numerator, so the function $f(x)$ that you want to converge to will be $f(x) \equiv 0$.

So, given $\epsilon>0$, can you find the value $N$ such that $\left|f_n(x)\right| < \epsilon$ is true?